# Why doesn't work next() with selector. Help me...!

Tags: jquery

```
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        // todo click down arrow
        var g = $('ol.list-group > a').hasClass('activeSelect');
        if (g == false) {
            $('a:not(.disable-li)').first().addClass('activeSelect');
        }
        var b = $('a.activeSelect');
        b.removeClass('activeSelect');
        b.next('a:not(disable-li)').first().addClass('activeSelect');
    }
```

Comment: Difficult to answer without the HTML, and what "doesn't work" means in this instance. Any errors?

Comment: I suspect you want `nextAll(...).first()`, but as popnoodles said...

Comment: next('a:not(.disable - li')

Answer (score 1):

You are missing class selector `.`

```
 b.next('a:not(.disable-li)').first().addClass('activeSelect');
```

Or you can try

```
b.nextUntil('a:not(.disable-li)').next().addClass('activeSelect');
```

Because next() will always return the next element even though you pass some class names/element identity.

Or like @TJ Crowder says,

```
b.nextAll('a:not(.disable-li)').first().addClass('activeSelect');
```

Comment: Almost certainly *not* `nextUntil`.